# How to specify a subfolder of Inbox using Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm trying to access a subfolder of "Inbox" named "subfolder" in outlook (2010) using Powershell.

```
$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)

# how do I specify a subfolder that's inside Inbox???
# I mean, "Inbox\subfolder" where "subfolder" is the name of the subfolder...
```

How do I specify this subfolder?

I'm sure this is really simple, which is why I am about to "lose it."  Thanks in advance!

*Later in my code, 
I search the body for a "searchterm" and send the results to a text file if there's a match.  The following code works for my Inbox:

```
$inbox.items | foreach {
if($_.body -match "searchterm") {$_.body | out-file -encoding ASCII foo.txt} # prints to file...
```

Instead of the inbox, I want to look at the subfolder of inbox as described above...

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

EDIT:

```
$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$targetfolder = $inbox.Folders | where-object { $_.name -eq "Subfolder" }
$targetfolder.items | foreach {
if($_.body -match "keyword") {$_.body | out-file -Append -encoding ASCII foo.txt} # keyword match prints body to file...
}
```

OK, I think this works now...

I don't know what I was doing wrong, although it's literally my first day using Powershell, so it's no surprise, really.

Comment: If it were VBScript, would it not be something like: Set myNewFolder = inbox.Folders("subfolder")

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$targetfolder = $inbox.Folders | where-object { $_.name -eq "subfolder" }
$targetfolder.items | where-object { $_.body -match "keyword" } | % { $_.body } # can then redirect the body to file etc.
```

EDIT: not sure why your newest edit wouldn't work. Yours looks to be similar in construction to the one I have above, which I verified against my own mailbox.

EDIT EDIT: Be sure that if you're using out-file, you append the results rather than overwriting with each match.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm looking into the options for outfile now... not as simple as > versus >> to me... but I will get there.

Comment: I added the append to the above code.  I've got a long way to go with what I really want to do here, but this really helps me out, thanks again!

Comment: What's about using Outlook with multiple smtp and Exchange accounts ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Where-Object cmdlet to filter the Folders returned from `$inbox.Folders`.

```
$Subfolder = $inbox.Folders | Where-Object -FilterScript { (Split-Path -Path $_.FolderPath -Leaf) -eq 'Subfolder' }
```

Here is an alternative / short-hand version of the above. This won't be quite as reliable, since you could have another folder called `MySubfolder` that's distinct from `Subfolder`.

```
$Subfolder = $inbox.Folders | ? { $_.FolderPath.EndsWith('Subfolder') }
```

Comment: Trevor, I'm not trying to be fresh, but couldn't there be an easier way to specify the path?  It wouldn't bother me if it were hard-coded (for now)... My intuitions are failing on this one, and I've been having a difficult time finding a proper example.  I tried your line to declare $subfolder and I couldn't get it to work...