# Start Outlook 2007 with Powershell, Display IMAP Inbox

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm starting to get into Powershell these days, and am trying to start up Outlook 2007 in a clean way (it should run on multiple computers without much or any modification) and show the first accounts (imap) inbox.

I already found the answer in [How to specify a subfolder of Inbox using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382980/how-to-specify-a-subfolder-of-inbox-using-powershell), however this focuses on the local Inbox at startup. We don't use the local inbox as all the clients have an IMAP Account, so it would be convenient to display it at startup.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The code I used from the above linked question was:

```
$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox);
$inbox.Display()
```

This, as mentioned above, opens the local inbox and I fail to find a command that selects the inbox of an IMAP Account.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us the code that you are working with, and let us know what issues you are having with it?

Comment: I edited my question above, thank you :) The issues I'm having with it are just that I try to get a pointer to a different inbox than the local inbox. I don't think GetDefaultFolder() is the right way here, but I wouldn't know any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's what I've used as an alternative to `GetDefaultFolder` in a script before. This looks at the available accounts, and tries to find one containing the user's login name (so if I login to my computer with a user name of TMTech it would look at all accounts that contain the string TMTech, such as TMTech@email.com). Then it looks at the folders for that account for one named Inbox, and away you go from there.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$MyAcct = $Namespace.Folders | ?{$_.Name -match $env:USERNAME}
$Inbox = $MyAcct.Folders | ?{$_.Name -match "Inbox"}
```

Now this does still reference the MAPI namespace, but I think the interop library includes everything in the MAPI namespace, so it should still work I think.

Comment: Haven't gotten around to testing on Outlook 2007, but it works fine with Outlook 2013 so I'm assuming it will work - thanks a lot!

Comment: Works for Outlook 2007 as well!